# How do I access #anchors from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, anchor

I dont think it's possible directly, so I considered using javascript to access the anchors and pass that to PHP, but I don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean "access"?

Comment: Can you expand on it more please? Are you trying to pass information to PHP when someone clicks on something or what? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: int he same way you pass variables through get, I need to pass #cars through to PHP so that is can query the database for for example cars.

Comment: @JamesVince: and why are you trying to use the `#` instead of passing variables through GET?

Comment: Because I am working with a wordpress theme that is filtering results based on #cars #houses for example, and I need to understand how its done so I can look for it or just bypass it and use my own querying based on this url system.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$.post('getHash.php', {hash: window.location.hash});
```

Than in your `getHash.php` file

```
<?php
   $hash = $_POST['hash'];
   /* ... */
?>
```

Still, your question does not provide enough information for us to answer it corectly.

Comment: That looks like the thing I need, but can I just do that? But it wont appear in the URL as #cars. I need people to be able to bookmark or retain that address in some way. Kinda like like twitter's hash bang. twitter.com/#!/cars

Comment: Why use hashtags then? You can store variables in the URL and access them in PHP like this: www.yoursite.com/page.php?hash=cars

Comment: @JamesVince: [Twitter don’t use hashbangs any more](http://storify.com/timhaines/hashbang-conversation?awesm=sfy.co_aUW&utm_campaign=&utm_medium=sfy.co-twitter&utm_source=t.co&utm_content=storify-pingback).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the hash portion of URLs (i.e. everything after `#`), that’s not sent to the server by web browsers. So you can’t access it from PHP.

Sounds like you’ve got the right approach for informing the server about hashes, i.e. using JavaScript. You can access the hash in browsers with `window.location.hash`. To send that to the server, you could use the XMLHTTPRequest object to POST it to the server.

Comment: Yes, but how do I pass the window.location.hash to a php variable?